# how to move an android view up and down smoothly 8 times?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

how to move an android view up and down smoothly 8 times?

Here is my code

```
        final TranslateAnimation breathUpTranslateAnimation =
          new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.05F);
        breathUpTranslateAnimation.setDuration(TOOLTIP_ANIM_DURATION);

        //breathUpTranslateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        breathUpTranslateAnimation.setRepeatCount(8);
        breathUpTranslateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    breathUpTranslateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    //breathUpTranslateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    toolTipLayout.startAnimation(breathUpTranslateAnimation);
```

but in reality, the view is moving up smoothly

and return very fast or immediately back to starting point.

I want it to be back smoothly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
breathUpTranslateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

Comment: Replace Animation.RESTART with Animation.REVERSE

Comment: yet there is a problem: the last leg is done with a jump and not smoothly. how can I change this?

Comment: will try, but it should split it equally between all legs, no?